# Can GKE cluster nodes be created without external IPs?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I noticed all the nodes created by GKE have ephemeral external IPs.

Is this necessary and can it be disabled? I'd rather not expose all nodes publicly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I noticed all the nodes created by GKE have ephemeral external IPs.
>   Is this necessary?

Yes. GCE VMs need an external IP address to make outbound requests to the internet, which includes the GCE APIs. Without external IPs, the VMs wouldn't be able to connect to the cluster control plane (Kubernetes apiserver), docker hub, gcr.io, etc.

> Can it be disabled?

Not at the current time.

Comment: Hi, do you have any official reference link / doc about this limitation ? ephemeral ip have a quota, how to workaround this ?

Comment: You can request a quota increase for ephemeral ips. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas, click edit, find the line for `In-use IP addresses` in the zone where you want to run your cluster and fill out the form.

Comment: Thank you, I did it, I just don't feel that it's very scalable.

Comment: Scalable in what sense? If you need a large cluster, you can request a large increase in quota (you will also need more cpus anyway). If you mean across multiple projects then you should look at using [folders](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders) to manage resources across multiple projects in your organization.

Comment: FWIW, I just did the quota request and it was done in about a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick comment for the future traveler. This is still not possible as of today but they are working on it

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I'd like to keep track of whether it's been implemented.

Comment: My company is using CGP to deploy our applications and we are paying for support so I use it to ask the question. They just told me that it is not possible today but already request by other company and they are working on it. Sadly they did not give me any date or way to track their progress.